# Extract OU and Domain from DistinguishedName

Tags: powershell, ou

I have a user named `Lamda` that I want to extract the OU and Domain sequence from the `DistinguishedName`.

For example, for the `DistinguishedName` of `CN=Lamda,OU=OU_Bloquage,DC=Adminstrateur,DC=6NLG-AD`

I want to extract the sequence `OU=OU_Bloquage,DC=Adminstrateur,DC=6NLG-AD` and assign to a variable.

I tried the following script but it did not work:

```
$var = dsquery user -name 'Lamda' | dsget user -dn [regex]::match($var,'(?=OU)(.*\n?)(?<=.)').Value
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: $var = dsquery user -name 'Lamda' | dsget user -dn

Comment: That just gets the user details, which I'd already assumed you had.  What have you done to try to extract the info you want?  Incidentally, why not use the [AD Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) instead of a command-line tool?  It's almost always easier to use a 'native' PowerShell command rather than external apps.

Comment: Okey I tried the following script but it did not work                                                              $var = dsquery user -name 'Lamda' | dsget user -dn                                        [regex]::match($var,'(?=OU)(.*\n?)(?<=.)').Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split by non-escaped comma once, discard the first substring:

```
$null,$ou = 'CN=Lamda,OU=OU_Bloquage,DC=Adminstrateur,DC=6NLG-AD' -split '(?<!\\),',2
```

Comment: The $ou variable ends up with } at the end ,how can I remove it

Comment: @MohamedKhalilHannachi `$ou.TrimEnd(')')`